# UIKit Nestable (or any event) with Angular 2

Tags: angular, events, uikit

how am I meant to get the event 'stop.uk.nestable'

(https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/nestable.html)

To trigger a method/function in my Angular 2 app?

I've tried a jscript call to it, nada, and I dont think viewchild-ing it helps